# Ordered List not Restarting

Tags: jquery, html

Currently i have written a table with individual ordered list inside.
However the problem is when i use jquery to get the index, i am getting the index of a continuous number.
I hope that someone is able to assist me restarting this number back to 1 for each ordered list.
I have tried  but it did not work. Mentioned below are my codes.
Thanks in advance

```
<tr>
<td>
    <ol start="1" class="selectable">
        <li class="ui-widget-content">0800 - 0830</li> 
        <li class="ui-widget-content">0830 - 0900</li>
    </ol>
</td>
<td>
    <ol start="1" class="selectable">
        <li class="ui-widget-content">0800 - 0830</li> 
        <li class="ui-widget-content">0830 - 0900</li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {

            $(".selectable li").css({"background":"white","color":"black"});

            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            var bookingHours = $( "#booking-hours" ).empty();
            var bookingPeriod = [];
            var count = 0;


            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(
                function() {
                    $( this ).css({"background":"#F39814","color":"white"});
                    var index = $( ".selectable li" ).index( this )+1;
                    bookingPeriod[count] = index;
                    count++;
                }
            );
            bookingHours.append( (count*0.5) + " Hours" );

            var bookingFrom = bookingPeriod[0];
            var bookingTo = bookingPeriod[bookingPeriod.length-1];

            result.append( ( bookingFrom ) + " to " + ( bookingTo ) );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your jQuery as well.

Comment: What jQuery code have you written?

Comment: Thanks so much for editing the codes earlier. Yea but here are my jquery codes

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = $( ".selectable li", $(this).parent() ).index( this )+1;
```

You can mention context also as its $(this).parent() in above example.

I have also created http://jsbin.com/welcome/22907/edit before your post update. Hope that will help.

Comment: it did not work. Thanks for your help anyway. The number being thrown kept being 0

Comment: I think, you are clicking on first item in lists, I wrote code by getting index, and jQuery starts index from 0. Try click on second items and you will get '1'.